# TCP client not responding in JAVA

Tags: java, networking, server, tcp, client

I was learning JAVA networking API and simple TCP server-client communication.
I have written the following two classes for client and server.
The issue is that my client is not responding i.e. the program is not terminating and it doesn't output anything .. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class client {

    public void go() {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",2323);

 InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            String reading = reader.readLine();


            PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            write.print("mynameistom");

           

            System.out.println(reading);


            reader.close();
            writeToServer.close();
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client;
        client.go();
    }
}
```

Server:

```
package TCP;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Server {

        public void go() {
        try {
        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(2323);


        Socket socket = serverSock.accept();
           
                InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                String messsage = reader.readLine();
              
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream())

        writer.println(message);
        writer.close();
        System.out.println(message);

        } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }



public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.go();
        }
        }
```

Comment: As usual. You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Add a line terminator, or use `println()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious thing is that the client isn't flushing, and is missing the new line.

```
        PrintWriter writeToServer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        writeToServer.print("network");
```

Should be either

```
        PrintWriter writeToServer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        writeToServer.println("network");
```

or

```
        PrintWriter writeToServer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        writeToServer.println("network");
        writeToServer.flush();
```

Comment: I applied this solution, but still client is not giving any output. 
I tried debugging client class, it stops at line 
            String serverReply = reader.readLine(); and never terminates.

Comment: My issue is resolved anyway, thanks for your input too :)

Comment: @Shaheer Your issue was resolved by the code in this answer.